# FB Prophet changes the training data

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I am working on a time series prediction with a dataset that has this header

| ds | y |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-01-31 | 39.667406 |
| 2018-02-28 | 42.091133 |
| 2018-03-31 | 40.845842 |
| 2018-04-30 | 42.177686 |
| 2018-05-31 | 42.087838 |

and fit the data to the model and did some predictions with the following code

```
Model = Prophet()
Model.fit(df_prophet_ventana)
future = Model.make_future_dataframe(periods=4, freq='M')

forecast = Model.predict(future)
forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail()
```

The problem is when I look at the values in forecast

```
forecast[['ds','yhat']].head()
```

it return a dataset with different values of the original data

| ds | yhat |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-01-31 | 41.508584 |
| 2018-02-28 | 41.518272 |
| 2018-03-31 | 41.528999 |
| 2018-04-30 | 41.539380 |
| 2018-05-31 | 41.549945 |

Why does the values change?